# В частности - нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Действие трудового правоотношения может быть прекращено по основаниям кодекса, в частности(,) в связи с истечением срока контракта.

Ставится ли в таких случаях запятая? Я думаю, что нет (по аналогии с "например"). И все же есть сомнения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я согласен, здесь полная аналогия c "наконец".

//-------
§ 93. Если вводное слово или вводное сочетание слов стоит в начале или в конце обособленного члена предложения, то оно не отделяется от него знаком препинания, т. е. запятые выделяют член предложения вместе с вводным словом:
...
Дана достаточно ясная характеристика, в частности декабриста Михаила Спиридова (Чив.), ср. На собрании вопрос, в частности, касался методов обучения;...  
(Лопатин)
//-------

http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=284 
http://orthographia.ru/punctum.php?paragraph=pg84.php